# is there a bulk exporter for etherpad?

Tags: etherpad

is there a bulk exporter for etherpad?

we might need one to document a series of etherpads, in a publishable form

best including the comments column,

my sources: Peter Murray-Rust's question and Friedrich Lindenberg's suggestion: http://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/okfn-discuss/2011-March/007643.html

Comment: Does it suffice to get the plain text export? I have a script to do that programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have direct access to the etherpad DB?
Otherwise, look for the readonly-links, but there you wouldn't get the "comments" = chat history, which you usually anyway have to load manually.

So probably, you'll need a custom export script. John who runs PrimaryPad might have something to sell, or if you have your own coders you could create a custom pad template with your wanted formatting, and add or dig out a feature to fill in that template with also the chat history.
I'm an (in)active committer to http://github.com/ether/pad and I'm fairly sure there doesn't exist any bulk export features. Anyway, what good is export without import.

Upgrading is painless -- etherpad has built in features to upgrade the database as needed, so just pull from the git repository. But perhaps pick a release tag like 1.0.1 to stay clear of the bleeding edge / trunk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the migration tool that will migrate from the old Etherpad to the latest Etherpad.  Once you do that you can just hit up the HTML endpoint of the pad IE http://newetherpad.okfn.org/p/foo/export/HTML

Updating Etherpad is really easy to do, just clone github.com/ether/etherpad-lite edit your settings.json, start etherpad then run bin/convert.js

That will take your old Etherpad data and move it through to the latest Etherpad.